# Echo Category form field type title in Module

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, module, joomla-3.4, module-params

I'm building a module and using the  Category Form Field Type, as outlined in the Joomla docs here https://docs.joomla.org/Category_form_field_type

In the module XML I've used the following:

```
<field name="catOne" type="category" extension="com_content" label="Select a category" description="" />
<field name="catTwo" type="category" extension="com_content" label="Select a category" description="" />
<field name="catThree" type="category" extension="com_content" label="Select a category" description="" />
<field name="catFour" type="category" extension="com_content" label="Select a category" description="" />
```

Whenever I echo these in the frontend, I'm just getting the category ID - how can I echo the category title and it's related URL for each of the above variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo have the ID of the category, so you can perform a database query to get the `title`, like so:

#### Get the title from the ID:

```
// Get the category parameter value 
// Define a default value of 0
$cat_id = $params->get('catOne', 0);

// Get instance of database connection
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Query the #__categories table in the database
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select($db->quoteName('title'))
      ->from($db->quoteName('#__categories'))
      ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. (int)$cat_id);
$db->setQuery($query);

// Try and get the result
try
{
    $result = $db->loadResult();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // If there is no result, make the variable empty
    $result = '';
}

// Display the result
echo $result;
```

#### Display a Link:

To display the URL for the category, you will need to import com_content's router:

```
require_once JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php';

$link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=' . $cat_id);

echo '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $result . '</a>';
```

#### For multiple params, use a function:

```
function displayCategoryLink($id)
{
    require_once JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php';

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($db->quoteName('title'))
          ->from($db->quoteName('#__categories'))
          ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. (int)$id);
    $db->setQuery($query);

    try
    {
        $result = $db->loadResult();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $result = '';
    }

    $link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=' . $id);   
    $html = '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $result . '</a>';

    return $html;
}


displayCategoryLink($params->get('catOne', 0));
displayCategoryLink($params->get('catTwo', 0));
displayCategoryLink($params->get('catThree', 0));
displayCategoryLink($params->get('catFour', 0));
```

The function above is just basic. I would of course suggest you put the function in a class, in a **helper.php** file and call it properly

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Lodder - how can I then echo the URL for this category?

Comment: If I have mroe than one category variable, how will this work also? I've updated the question above

Comment: @RustyJoomla - More than welcome ;)

Comment: One last question, how can I seperate the $link and the $result - so for example if I want to add a href onto a button but have the category name as text within the button?

Comment: @RustyJoomla The way I've written the function for you in the last code snippet, this outputs a clickable link with the Category Title as the actual link, e.g: [Some Title](http://gooele.co.uk). Maybe I mis-read your comment if you're referring to something different

Comment: Thanks @Lodder - I've opened a new question here http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/13807/separate-link-and-title-from-function