# Separate Link and Title from function

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, module, joomla-3.4

I have another question which was kindly answered by @Lodder here:

[Echo Category form field type title in Module](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/13796/echo-category-form-field-type-title-in-module/13797#13797)

In the link which is produced, I want to separate the link and title from the category, meaning I can add the link to a parent button and the title within that button - how can this be done using the following html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-<?php echo $buttonWidth;?>">
        <div class="row">
        <a href="<?php echo $categoryLinkOne; ?>">
            <button class="btn btn-default col-md-12" type="button">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="<?php echo $moduleLoc,$iconOne; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <?php echo $categoryTitleOne; ?></h3>
                </div>
            </button>
        </a>
        </div>

    <?php if($showIntroTextOne==1):?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p><?php echo $introTextOne; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

<?php if($params->get('useTwo')==1){?>  
    <div class="col-md-<?php echo $buttonWidth;?>">
        <div class="row">
        <a href="<?php echo $categoryLinkTwo; ?>">
            <button class="btn btn-default col-md-12" type="button">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="<?php echo $moduleLoc,$iconTwo; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <?php echo $categoryTitleTwo; ?></h3>
                </div>
            </button>
        </a>
        </div>

    <?php if($showIntroTextTwo==1):?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p><?php echo $introTextTwo; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a HTML markup example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use the function I wrote for this.

So, we're going to add another argument to the function to define the type of button/link we want to display and set a default value of `normal`

```
function displayCategoryLink($id, $type = 'normal')
{
    require_once JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php';

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select($db->quoteName('title'))
          ->from($db->quoteName('#__categories'))
          ->where($db->quoteName('id') . ' = '. (int)$id);
    $db->setQuery($query);

    try
    {
        $result = $db->loadResult();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $result = '';
    }

    $link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=' . $id); 
    
    if ($type == 'extended')
    {
        $html = '
        <a href="' . $link . '">
            <button class="btn btn-default col-md-12" type="button">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="' . $moduleLoc,$iconOne . '" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h3>' .  $result . '</h3>
                </div>
            </button>
        </a>';
    }
    else
    {
        $html = '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $result . '</a>';
    }

    return $html;
}


displayCategoryLink($params->get('catOne', 0));
displayCategoryLink($params->get('catTwo', 0));
displayCategoryLink($params->get('catThree', 0), 'extended');
displayCategoryLink($params->get('catFour', 0), 'extended');
```

Please note that you're also using `$moduleLoc,$iconOne` for the image source, so you'll either need to pass these values through the function as an argument, or define them yourself inside the function.

### Update:

Here if your updated code that should be in the **default.php**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-<?php echo $buttonWidth;?>">
        <div class="row">
            <?php displayCategoryLink($params->get('catOne', 0), 'extended'); ?>
        </div>

        <?php if($showIntroTextOne == 1):?>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p><?php echo $introTextOne; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <?php if($params->get('useTwo') == 1) : ?>  
        <div class="col-md-<?php echo $buttonWidth;?>">
            <div class="row">
                <?php displayCategoryLink($params->get('catTwo', 0), 'extended'); ?>
            </div>

            <?php if($showIntroTextTwo == 1):?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p><?php echo $introTextTwo; ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but how can this work if I have multiple buttons with different categories? It works great for one button, but what about two, three or four buttons? I've updated the HTML example above

Comment: @RustyJoomla - I've updated my answer implementing the function in the code you provided in your question

Comment: Thanks Lodder, this isn't outputting the variables in the frontend though unfortunately. It's only showing the '$showIntroText###' data

Comment: @RustyJoomla - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29706/lodder-rusty

Comment: Can't comment in the chat room :(